# Утилиты для поиска дубликатов файлов на диске

Tags: visual-studio, c++

- Поиск по диску C;
- Ввод файла в программу через кнопку "обзор";
- Вывод списка директорий, где находяться дубликаты файла;

Comment: Вам написать или готовую для работы? Или рассказать как такое пишется?,

Comment: Написать было бы очень хорошо.

Comment: Но за любую помощь огромное спасибо!

Comment: http://www.3dnews.ru/software/duplicate/

Comment: хм..... исходник мне нужен)

Comment: Ищите исходники утилиты fdupes.